Could not create task ':app:uploadSentryProguardMappingsProductionrelease'
I have been trying to integrate sentry for react native v0.63.5. Sentry docs states that the minimum version for react-native should be >= 0.65 I am trying to run a project using npx react-native run-android.
error upon build failure

Could not create task ':app:uploadSentryProguardMappingsProductionrelease'.
'org.gradle.api.provider.Provider com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant.getMappingFileProvider()'

Following are the changes that I did in the project.
android/build.gradle > depedencies
classpath("io.sentry:sentry-android-gradle-plugin:2.1.4")
I tried downgrading the gradle plugin version to 2.x.x
npm package
"@sentry/react-native": "^5.26.0"
android/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: "io.sentry.android.gradle"
project.ext.sentryCli = [
    logLevel: "debug"
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/@sentry/react-native/sentry.gradle"

gradle version
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
I am still trying but could not figure out where's the problem.
Edit 1: Downgraded AGP to 1.7.36 and the build was successful.
Q2: Sentry.nativeCrash() or throw new Error("XXX") events are not getting captured on sentry platform. This might be due to the downgraded AGP version.
Update on Q2: The account has exhausted it's event limit.
